# How to generate script file of a database in postgresql with insert queries instead of copy query?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-scripts

In **postgresql**, I had taken backup. That file didn't have any insert queries instead it used Some copy statments like

```
COPY user_customers (userid, customerlist) FROM stdin;
anil    customer1:customer2
babu    customer1:customer4
srikakulapu customer1:customer2
\.
```

But i want insert statements of that table....

How could I get the insert statements of table data in backup file?

Besides that I couldn't execute `pg_dump` command....

I am generating backup file by right clicking on a table by chosing backup option..

Kindly help me out... Otherwise I have to rewrite all the insert queries manually for documentation....

waiting for your help.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.Open command prompt

2.Make it to point to bin in postgres folder

3.execute following command


pg_dump --column-inserts -U postgres databasename>filename



4. File will be stored in bin folder of postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use pg_dump , then you can add the `-inserts` parameter.

> Dump data as INSERT commands (rather than COPY).

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/app-pgdump.html)

If you could add the code of your attempt to use pg_dump, we could solve this problem, too.

Comment: But pg_dump command is not working... DO I need to create any extenstion?????? @akkusativobjekt